# using parameters in date function in excel

Tags: excel, reference, vba

I want to use the date function in an Excel VBA script using a parameter value.

```
D = "=Date(y,m,d)"
```

where `d`, `m`, `y` are parameters that are fetched during running the macro.

The problem for me is that I have to maintain the date format for the cell like `"dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **VBA** use Dateserial()  like:

```
Sub dural()
    y = 2014
    m = 3
    d = 2
    Range("A1").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
    Range("A1").Value = DateSerial(y, m, d)
End Sub
```

Note the order of parameters!